# NSArray is empty when accesing in a method of the UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, uitableview

I'm trying to do a `UITableView`, but I'm totally stuck. My problem is I'm trying to do the method `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and for filling the cells I have a `NSArray` of `myObject`, wich is set by another class via a setter in my `UITableViewController`.

My problem is that when I'm gonna use that array, it is totally empty, and I don´t know why -- when I do the setter, the object has data, but when I try to do the getter inside the method above, it is empty. Can someone tell me why, and how can I fix it?

My setter:

```
- (void)setmyObjectList:(NSArray *)list{          
      _myObjectList = list;
}
```

MyObjectList is declared in the .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myObjectList;
```

And this code is in the Controller that call my TableViewController via a segue:

```
myTableViewController *myTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
[myTVC setPharmaciesList:self.list];
```

Maybe i didn't explain well: I have a class that has a NSArray with the the objects I wanna show in my TableView. So via a segue I set this NSArray in the TableViewController. In the setter when I do a NSLog all the data is in the NSArray in the property of the NSTableViewController, but when I try to access in the method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: the info is empty. Why? I have no idea.

Thanks :P

Comment: Post the setter method, and the code where you call the setter.

Comment: Stacky i m a bit confused buddy. i dont really understand what u are trying to do..  For basic it is always handy to NSLog the NSArray to see what is really inside the Array. but first can u please enlighten me more Thanks :)

Comment: For one thing, the "m" in setmyObjectList should be capitalized.

Comment: I'm gonna tried to explain :) I have a class that has a NSArray with the the objects I wanna show in my TableView. So via a segue I set this NSArray in the TableViewController. In the setter when I do a NSLog all the data is in the NSArray in the property of the NSTableViewController, but when I try to access in the method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: the info is empty. Why? I have no idea. Thanks :P

Comment: Ok, guys, I fixed it. It was cuz the properties of the objects that my NSArray contains, were weak. So i lost the pointer to the data. Thanks for your interest and help :)

Answer (score 0):

First, don't override the setter method since youre not doing anything special there. Second, where do you create the array that you later set your property to by calling
 [myTVC setPharmaciesList:self.list];

I.e. where do you populate self.list?

Comment: I fixed it. It was cuz i declared weak the properties of the object inside the NSArray. Beginner's mistake!!! :) Thanks for your help